# Using Threads With A Stack (C++)

Tags: c++

I try to create a stack with using Threads, my code:

Push function (m is mutex)

```
void Stack::Push(int num){  
    m.lock();
    sta[current++] = num;
    m.unlock();
}
```

Pop function:

```
int Stack::Pop(){
    if (current > 0){
        m.lock();
        int a = sta[--current];
        m.unlock();
        return a;
    }
    return sta[0];
}
```

The Main:

```
void threadsPrint(string s){
    m1.lock();
    cout << s << endl;
    m1.unlock();
}

void func(Stack & t){
    threadsPrint("T1 Push 1\n");
    t.Push(1);
    threadsPrint("T1 Push 2\n");
    t.Push(2);
    threadsPrint("T1 Push 3\n");
    t.Push(3);
    threadsPrint("T1 Push 4\n");
    t.Push(4);
    threadsPrint("T1 Push 5\n");
    t.Push(5);
    threadsPrint("T1 Push 6\n");
    t.Push(6);
}

void func2(Stack & t){
    threadsPrint("T2 Pop "+to_string(t.Pop())+"\n");
    threadsPrint("T2 Pop " + to_string(t.Pop()) + "\n");
    threadsPrint("T2 Pop " + to_string(t.Pop()) + "\n");
    threadsPrint("T2 Pop " + to_string(t.Pop()) + "\n");
    threadsPrint("T2 Pop " + to_string(t.Pop()) + "\n");
    threadsPrint("T2 Pop " + to_string(t.Pop()) + "\n");
}

int main(){
    Stack t;

    thread t1(func,ref(t));
    thread t2(func2,ref(t));
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
   T1 Push 1

   T2 Pop -842150451

   T1 Push 2

   T2 Pop 1

   T1 Push 3

   T2 Pop 2

   T1 Push 4

   T2 Pop 3

   T1 Push 5

   T2 Pop 4

   T1 Push 6

   T2 Pop 5
```

I know it's bad code, but I'm just trying to work with threads
I still don't get proper result, what do I have to fix the code?

Comment: What result do you get, and what do you expect?

Comment: A better place to post this would be http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: *'what do I have to do to fix the code'* what is it currently not doing?

Comment: Scott, I have added the output, what I expect them to work together as a stack (LIFO) and each thread will change the currect separately

Comment: aruisdante, this isn't work like a stack

Comment: **Minimal** code example *that is compilable to reproduce the error*. Input. Observed output. Expected output. -- Just *in case* the point of the question is the negative number for T2 Pop, well, obviously you don't properly initialize `Stack::current`, and you `Pop()` before you `Push()`...

Comment: Also `Stack::Pop` isn't thread safe, you're doing a non atomic read outside of the protecting mutex.

Comment: A not about threads and stacks/queues; Just because it's 'thread-safe', doesn't mean accessing it from two different threads will do what you expect. Pushing from one thread and popping another thread with zero synchronization is going to result in a totally arbitrary output order. In most cases, 'thread safe' simply guarantees that when any thread accesses the container it will always be in a consistent state for the entirety of the operation.

Comment: Based on your comments I understand I did really bad work:(
How can I make the code for thread-saftly? Don't do it with mutex?

Comment: What behaviour do you want from the Pop()... perhaps you want it to wait for something to be Pushed() before it returns?

Comment: What's your initial value of current ?

Comment: Scott,if I add: while (current == 0)
  Sleep(1); It's supposed to help?

Comment: a4anuarag, int current = 0;

Comment: As @ScottLangham says, there are three primary classes of thread-safe stacks/queues: Non-blocking, which allow thread-safe read/write access and will simply return 'empty' if a read is performed when there is nothing on the stack/queue, 'blocking', which will block the read (or write if full) thread until there is something on the container to read, and 'synchronizing', which is essentially a blocking container with a size of one; this results in a write blocking until a read is performed, and a read blocking until a write is performed, which will effectively 'synchronize' two threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may want to use a condition variable in addition to the mutex so that the Pop function will wait for something to be pushed if there is nothing on the stack.

In Push() you can call `cv.notify_one();` and in Pop() you can call `cv.wait(m, []{return current > 0;});`

See an example here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Comment: I'm trying to do as you wrote is giving me an error on the current variable

Answer (score 2):

```
if current > 0){
    m.lock();
```

You cannot check `current` outside the `m.lock()`. Is subject to race conditions.

```
int Stack::Pop(){
  m.lock();
  int a = current ? sta[--current] : sta[0];
  m.unlock();
  return a;
}
```

But your stack is still fundamentally unable to distinguish between popping the last item or popping on an empty stack. Personally I would prefer something like:

```
boolean Stack::Pop(int& val){
  boolean ret = false;
  m.lock();
  if (current) {
     val = sta[--current];
     ret = true;
  }
  m.unlock();
  return ret;
}
```

The problem of waiting for the stack to grow, when empty, is delegated to the caller. A fully fledged producer-consumer stack with wait and signaling is beyond the scope here.

Of course, `lock()`/`unlock()` should be [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

Answer (score 0):

One possible interleaving that would give the first few values you're seeing:

```
T1                                   T2
threadsPrint("T1 Push 1\n");
                                     threadsPrint("T2 Pop "+to_string(t.Pop())+"\n");
t.Push(1);
```

When T2 executes `t.Pop()` you'll get a garbage value, and T1 printed its output before it pushed, so the trace is wrong.

To fix the trace so it reflects the operations better, you need to move the trace output inside the lock (or add yet another lock).
To fix the "pop-bug", you need to wait until there's something on the stack before you pop anything.

Answer (score 0):

As per my observation the code is prone to race condition i.e. where the output of the program depends on the scheduling of its instructions.

looking at your code let's consider this scheduling scenario.

> First thread 1 is scheduled and it enters func.
>
> prints  "T1 Push 1"
>
> Context switch to T2 before it entered into push routine. Current
>   remains 0 and nothing written over it.
>
> prints "T2 Pop" and calls pop. Now doing --current will make you access
>   stack[0] i.e. a garbage value. Zero if stack is global or some bad value otherwise.
>
> Context switch back to t1 and continues at "T1 Push 2" and so on.

Hence the output which you're getting. It may give correct output a few times but if scheduling happens differently, it gives bad output.

So when your pop thread hits current 0 instead of returning stack[0] which may be garbage its wise to wait until something is pushed into stack.

I've written the code using wait and signal mechanism using pthreads.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t condv;

pthread_mutexattr_t mattr;
pthread_condattr_t cattr;

int  FLAG= 0; //for wait and notify.

int current = 0;
int s[100] ; //stack


void push(int num)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    cout<<"push: curr "<<current<<endl;
    s[current++] = num;
    FLAG = 1; //Done pushing. Set flag.
    pthread_cond_signal(&condv); //notify other thread
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); // release mutex
}

int pop()
{
    int a = -1;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while(FLAG == 0) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&condv,&mutex); //wait until the FLAG is unset.
    }
    if(current > 0)
    {
        cout<<"pop: curr "<<current<<endl;
        a = s[--current];
        if(current == 0) //If you're removing the last element of stack unset FLAG.
            FLAG = 0;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        return a;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return a;
}

void* t1(void *arg)
{
    cout<<"pushing 1\n";
    push(1);

    cout<<"pushing 10\n";
    push(10);

    cout<<"pushing 12\n";
    push(12);

    cout<<"pushing 4\n";
    push(4);

    cout<<"pushing 6\n";
    push(6);

    cout<<"pushing 7\n";
    push(7);
}

void* t2(void *arg)
{
    cout<<"Popped "<<pop()<<endl;
    cout<<"Popped "<<pop()<<endl;
    cout<<"Popped "<<pop()<<endl;
    cout<<"Popped "<<pop()<<endl;
    cout<<"Popped "<<pop()<<endl;
    cout<<"Popped "<<pop()<<endl;
}


int main()
{
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;

    pthread_mutexattr_init(&mattr);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, &mattr); 

    pthread_condattr_init(&cattr);
    pthread_cond_init(&condv, &cattr);  

    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &t1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, &t2, NULL);


    pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&mattr);
    pthread_condattr_destroy(&cattr);


    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

return 0;
}
```